# Is current Gothic ablaut paradigm correct?

Tags: gothic

Slahan is a Class 6 verb with the ablaum paradigm: a ō ō a
but we have slauhts that doesn't use it.

compare

fral**iu**san fral**u**sts
gak**iu**san gak**u**sts

ablaum paradigm: iu au u u

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand quite what you’re asking here. _Slauhts_ is not a verbal form in the _slahan_ paradigm, so you wouldn’t (necessarily) expect it to follow any particular verb class ablaut pattern. Are you asking why it’s _slauhts_ and not _slahts_ (when ostensibly it comes from _*slahtiz_)?

Comment: "You wouldn’t (necessarily) expect it to follow any particular verb class ablaut pattern." Why do you think so?

Comment: Why do you think it should? _Slaughter_ in English doesn’t follow the ablaut pattern of _slay/slew_ either. Nouns are generally derived from the root itself, often at a time before the language-specific ablaut patterns of strong verbs settled. Most nouns synchronically derived specifically from verbs are based on the present stem, but _slauhts_ is not one of them. It is arguably still derived from the verb synchronically in Gothic, but irregularly so (or based on a regularity I’m not familiar with).

Comment: "Most nouns synchronically derived specifically from verbs are based on the present stem" It is absolutely wrong. Where did you get that from?

Comment: How is it wrong? When we synchronically derive a noun from a verb, we generally do so from what we perceive to be the ‘basic’ stem, which in Germanic languages is the present stem. We go for a drive (not a *drove), we make drawings (not *drewings), Germans have _Beziehungen_ (not _*Bezogungen_), Gothic slander was _bihait_ (not _*bihaihait_), etc. If you have any evidence to the contrary, you’ll have to present it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet haitan is a Class 7a verb that doesn't have ablaut at all. This class also doesn't have a reduplication in Past Participle. I ask about ancient Germanic / IE languages (not about modern English / German) You may see biegen Bucht, tief taufen, riechen Rauch etc.

Comment: But those were not synchronically formed from the verb at a stage when the Germanic strong-verb ablaut patterns had settled. They were formed earlier on (most probably within IE itself) based on how derivation worked _at that time_, which is different from how it works in Germanic. In IE, you’d expect _*-ti-_ nouns to have zero-grade in the weak stem, and this was often generalised in Germanic. The IE root for _*slahana-_ is somewhat dubious to begin with, but likely didn’t have a zero-grade, so _*slahtiz_ may be inherited, but it’s more likely to be a later, Germanic formation.

Comment: There’s also PG _*slahtuz_, which seems to be just a variant of the same word and may explain why the Gothic form is _slauhts_ rather than just _*slahts_. But the critical point here is that noun derived synchronically at a stage when the Germanic ablaut patterns had already settled generally use the present stem as their basis, while earlier, inherited formations do not necessarily use a basis that fits neatly into the Germanic ablaut patterns.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Your comments here would make a good answer!